# Boolean Mode Where Match Query with Dynamic Against Values, using PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, dynamic-programming

I want to query mysql with a `Where Match` query using `mysqli prepared statements`. The problem is the `Boolean Mode AGAINST values`,

normally: `(+value1 +value2 +value IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

but the problem is that I can't use it in prepared statements e.g. `(? ? ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)` because the number of values will differ, its not fixed.

I tried this code:

```
$keywords = explode(" ", $SearchResults->squery);   
foreach($keywords as $key=>$value)
{
    $keywords[$key] = '+'.$value;
}
$keywords = implode(",", $keywords);
$dbconnect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT `postid` FROM `espina5_jotecodb`.`posttd` WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $keywords)
if($stmt->execute())
{
    $stmt->bind_result($col1);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        echo $col1."<br>";
    }
}
$dbconnect->close();
```

`$keywords` during `bind_param` will have a single string containing `+value1 +value2 +value3`

The problem with the above code is that its not reading the values individually but as a whole, i think its because of the single `?` when the statement was prepared and single `s` during bind. I assumed I could do it like that, guess I was wrong.

So anyway the above code will result in reading the first value and disregard the succeeding values because the value is treated as a single value. So I am asking how can I achieve prepared statement queries with dynamic values for the boolean mode? Should I resort to querying the database individually per value?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it just wrong way.

> normally: (+value1 +value2 +value IN BOOLEAN MODE)

it is not. *Normally* it have to be

```
('+value1 +value2 +value' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

In quotes and **without commas**

the same goes with using placeholders: you have to assemble your search string in PHP, and then bind it whole via single placeholder.